# Why does " ?[^a-z\-\+]hit[^a-z\-\+]" NOT match "hit" (without space as first char?)

Tags: php, regex

i am back with a regex problem - i need to test a string for the occureance of pattern - it can be hidden somewhere in the string - right in front, in front but preceded with a blank, somewhere in between or at the end, maybe at the end followed by a blank.

i thought this regex might work - but it doesnt do the trick:

```
/ ?[^a-z\-\+]hit[^a-z\-\+]/
```

since it only shows the first hit when its preceded with a blank - since i tagged the first part with question mark - i thought the first char may also be omitted - please put me back on the tracks again an tell me where i am wrong...

I made a fiddle here: http://regexr.com/38lcq ( edit: i just tried out "Niet the Dark Absol"s Regex - better but still gives more matches than i want ...)

Comment: What are you expecting to match with your regex pattern?
Please put some examples of things that should be and shouldn't be matched.

Comment: Also, use http://regex101.com/ to try out and get explained of your regex patterns, it's very useful to learning regex.

Comment: Can you give examples of what you're running through the regex, too? Try using debuggex.com

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because your `[^a-z\-+]` requires at a character to be before your "target" `hit`.

Try: `/\bhit\b/` - The use of `\b` indicates a word boundary.

You can be more specific too:

```
/(?<![a-z0-9+-])hit(?![a-z0-9+-])/i
```

This uses negative lookbehind and lookahead to exclude what you don't want.

Comment: @Lupo you need to clarify exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @Niet This will not work if the target is preceeded by non-whitespace characters, which it may be.

Comment: @muppetjones - the background is i need to identify a given name in a string which can be preceded by a blank, if not at first position, and can be followed by a blank - if not on very last pos. the regex shall only find the "name" not "part-name" or "namepart" or "name+something", just "name"... i am helping me right now with `if (strpos(' '.$stringToSeach.' ', ' ' . $stringToFind . ' ') !== false) {` - its not very elegant - but nevertheless it works for the moment... best regards. lupo